# Как удалить VHD из Учетной записи хранения Azure (или найти чем используется)

Tags: azure

В Microsoft Azure остался VHD от старой виртуалки и никак не хочет удаляться, говорит, что используется. Виртуалки уже давно все пересозданы.

При попытке удаления пишет:

> There is currently a lease on the container and no lease ID was specified in the request. RequestId:0a4101fd-0001-000a-76d3-587cb9000000 Time:2016-01-27T07:21:56.6000523Z

В какую сторону «копать»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего остался диск или образ от виртуалки. Для того что бы удалить VHD сначала убедись в том, что твой диск/виртуалка не могут быть найдены в следующих подпунктах старого портала:

- Виртуальные машины --> Диски
- Виртуальные машины --> Образы

Если всё же там что-то нашел, то сначала удали, а потом проконтроллируй удалился ли VHD. По началу часто напарывался на данную проблематику.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно на _старом_ портале есть пункт образы, где и была проблема!